# Prefab with Sub-Elements Expansion Button Missing in Project Panel

Tags: unity

I have been following along with a course. In this course a GameObject called "Path (0)" is added, this GameObject then has three sub-GameObjects ("Waypoint (0/1/2)"). In the tutorial, the guy drags the parent GameObject "Path (0)" into a folder called Paths in the Project panel to create a prefab. This prefab is shown with a handle to expand it. He then expands this prefab to see the sub-elements which can be dragged into the Inspector, as shown below (expand button highlighted with red box)

[image]

When I perform these operations, the Project panel does not have an expand button on the "Path" prefab (see below)

[image]

Why does my prefab object in the Project panel not have these expansion buttons?

I can get around this, by using the prefab instance in the Hierarchy panel, but this is a much longer process than being able to access the object from the Project panel.

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: This might be due to the new nested prefab support that was added in a recent version, which meant overhauling how prefabs are edited, and removed some.of the options for editing prefabs in the project folder directly.

Comment: Right, okay. The course is definitely using an older version that what I have. Is there a way to turn this functionality back on, or is it gone for good? It is definitely a more efficient way of working when performing certain tasks.

Comment: This new prefab system has been asked for a long time by a lot of people. The old one is gone and the new one is much better. For info on the new nested prefabs you can watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5q1An6SFe40